# Workaround to find exact midnight within summertime in Php7

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Ok, this is definitely a PHP 7 bug.
My question is: do you know any reliable workaround?

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-10-14', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
print_r($date1);
print_r('<br/>');
print_r('<br/>');
$date2 = new DateTime('2017-10-15', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
print_r($date2);
print_r('<br/>');
print_r('<br/>');
$date3 = new DateTime('2017-10-16', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
print_r($date3);
```

This would give me midnight for each day, right? Wrong.

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-10-14 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo ) 

DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-10-15 01:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo ) 

DateTime Object ( [date] => 2017-10-16 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo )
```

It is one in the morning on the 15th. Is putting the offset to -2 and adding one hour. It happens always in the 15th.
Phpversion is 7.0.22

I really need to be able to reliably find midnight! :)

Comment: If it helps any... this also happens on PHP 5 (I copy/pasted your code to a test script on our server, and it results the same). Yet interestingly, when I use 'America/Los_Angeles' for the timezone (our default), the time is always 00:00:00 !!

Comment: This looks like a DST issue, as the 15th of october drops to -2 while the 14th is -3. The compensation is that midnight rolls around, but you lose an hour instantly. As the 15th of september and august do not present this problem.

Comment: There's a whole host of [DateTime bugs related to transitions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74274)

Comment: This isn't a bug.  It's reality.  Midnight doesn't exist on that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is one in the morning on the 15th...
>   I really need to be able to reliably find midnight!

You can't.  There *is* no local midnight in São Paulo on October 15th, 2017.  It doesn't exist.  As the local time approached midnight, it moved forward to 1:00 am for the start of daylight saving time.  Counting in microseconds, it went as follows:

```
..
2017-10-14 23:59:59.999998 UTC-03:00 (BRT)
2017-10-14 23:59:59.999999 UTC-03:00 (BRT)
2017-10-15 01:00:00.000000 UTC-02:00 (BRST)
2017-10-15 01:00:00.000001 UTC-02:00 (BRST)
...
```

Refer to [this site](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/sao-paulo?year=2017) for a visualization.